# Any value in JavaScript/HTML Decoupling? if so how?

Tags: javascript, html

Lately I've been writing more and more JavaScript for the websites I've been creating.  And I can't help but think that I'm doing something wrong, or there has to be a better way.

I have a clean separation of concerns on the server side, but on the client side, I find myself having entire sections of JavaScript that are dependent on specific element id's and class names, etc. For example, on one page, that has a lot of form fields, I may have a section of code that looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#ButtonID1").button();
     $("#Grid").someGridFunction();
     $(".data-fields").datepicker();
     $(".submit-links").click(function() { this.closest("form").submit(); });
});
```

What I'd almost prefer is some way for the HTML elements to request to obtain certain functionality.  Something like:

```
<input type="text" data-make="datepicker" />
```

But even that is flawed, because customization of that would require more and more attributes on the HTML element to detail specifics.  I had a similar setup done with KnockoutJS and I really wasn't happy with the HTML that was required.

Maybe something along the lines of this:

```
<input type="text" data-init="buildDefaultDatePicker" />
```

where "buildDefaultDatePicker" is a JavaScript function that handles the necessary work.

In the end, the question I have is two fold.  Is there any value in separating the JavaScript from the UI in regards to specific element ids and class names.  And if so, what patterns, and or methods have you used to achieve this?

(Note, I'm using jQuery syntax above, but I think this question is framework agnostic, so shouldn't matter for the answers)

Comment: This is a script. But if you can highlight your storyline people can answer it!!!

Comment: Eh?  Not sure what you're saying here.   I gave background, my thoughts, and asked the question out right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a class to signify the elements you want to attach behavior to. It has a semantic meaning, and you aren't coupling the html IDs or their locations into the javascript.

In the likely event that you need some specifics, like say a minimum or maximum date on a date picker, a light sprinkling of data attributes I think is an elegant way to provide it. But anything that would require more than a few data attributes is probably, in reality, a whole new kind of thing that deserves its own class, thus removing the need for the data attributes. For example, you might have a datepicker class, and find yourself constantly providing a minimum date of today to force a future date selection. Well, just make a 'futuredatepicker' class instead.

Comment: I'm not following you.  So I have a class that does the work, I understand that, how do you make it connect to the HTML element without tying the script to the element?

Comment: By class I mean a css class. <input type="text" class="datepicker" /> for example. Then you do $(".datepicker").datePicker(). There's no real coupling between html and js here, in the sense that your js code does not know about any ids or the html structure. It's more meaningful than using a "data-fields" class, too.

Comment: I've done this a lot in the past, I just don't like it that I occasionally have to add css classes to attributes that are there solely for JavaScript selection purposes.  Not to mention it's not really re-usable at all.

Comment: Choose your poison, I guess. Personally I find the css class approach elegant, and it's not at all outside of the bounds of what the class attribute was meant for. Think of css styling as just one consumer of the attribute. About re-usable, I don't see why not. You could have site-specific plugins or bootstrap scripts that do nothing but apply the appropriate plugins to all the possible classes. And using a build step you could even organize them all into individual scripts that get combined together at build time.

Comment: Revisiting this after a year and I find myself doing things very similar to this.  I agree, it's simple, and elegant, and depending on class names, it's pretty clear what's being accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you've got the right idea already (using classes to apply JavaScript enhancement to specific elements). Using a custom attribute such as `data-make` or `data-init` would be just another (more fiddly) way of doing the same thing. The way you have things already, specific classes can be used as the request to obtain certain functionality.

The method I'd advise is keeping a clean separation between your HTML and JavaScript. The JavaScript should always be in external files, and written to target page elements on `$(document).ready` to provide the requested functionality.

Comment: My scripts are in separate files. Also I clearly stated how I'm trying to avoid the $(document).ready call and all the ID's referenced in the body of that call that I'm already using.

Comment: Ok, that's great. What I'm trying to say is that you're doing it the right way already and there isn't a better way to attach JavaScript to HTML elements. You're maintaining a good degree of separation by saving the script externally, and the JavaScript enhances the basic HTML UI (i.e. you could still type a date without the date picker). Basically, the push of new functionality has to come from the JavaScript. It's impossible for the HTML to pull the JavaScript, but it can have classes/ids attached to get the functionality you need pushed to it.

Comment: I think there's always a better way.  We just might not know what it is yet.  Here's a fiddle I've been toying with:  http://jsfiddle.net/awgaM/1/